# Binary Search Tree Inorder Traversal

Tags: binary-search-tree

I am confused by this code:

```
void in_order_traversal_iterative(BinaryTree *root) {
  stack<BinaryTree*> s;
  BinaryTree *current = root;
  while (!s.empty() || current) {
    if (current) {
      s.push(current);
      current = current->left;
    } else {
      current = s.top();
      s.pop();
      cout << current->data << " ";
      current = current->right;
    }
  }
}
```

We set a pointer to point to root. Then if it exists, then push the current (which is root currently) into the stack. I do not see why we push the whole tree into the stack initially, instead of just the value of the data the node holds. Am I missing something completely or not understanding why it would work this way? I cannot comprehend why we push the whole tree in, rather than a single node...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the fact that after a node is popped, its right child must still be traversed:

```
  current = s.top();
  s.pop();
  cout << current->data << " ";
  current = current->right;
```

If you had only the data on the stack, this would be impossible.  The loop invariant is that the stack holds exactly those nodes with un-traversed right children.

Another way to see what's going on is to transform the recursive traversal to the iterative by algebra:

```
traverse(node) {
  if (node) {
    traverse(node->left);
    visit(node);
    traverse(node->right);
  }
}
```

First convert the tail call to iteration. We do this by updating the argument and replacing the recursive call with a `goto` the start of the function:

```
traverse(node) {
 start:
  if (node) {
    traverse(node->left);
    visit(node);
    node = node->right;
    goto start;
  }
}
```

The `goto` and `if` are the same as a `while`, so we have so far

```
traverse(node) {
  while (node) {
    traverse(node->left);
    visit(node);
    node = node->right;
  }
}
```

Replacing the other recursive call requires us to simulate the call stack of the compiler's runtime environment.  We do that with an explicit stack.

```
traverse(node) {
 start:
  while (node) {
    stack.push(node);   // save the value of the argument.
    node = node->left;  // redefine it the same way the recursive call would have
    goto start;         // simulate the recursive call
                        // recursive call was here; it's gone now!
   recursive_return:    // branch here to simulate return from recursive call
    visit(node);
    node = node->right;
  }
  // simulate the recursive return: if stack has args, restore and go to return site
  if (!stack.empty()) {
    node = stack.pop();  // restore the saved parameter value
    goto recursive_return;
  }
}
```

Though it's ugly, this is a way that always works to implement iterative versions of recursive code.   (It's more complicated if there are multiple non-tail recursive calls, but not much.) And I'm sure you can see the similarity to your code.

We can even get rid of the ugliness with more algebra.  First, it's not hard to see this code:

```
 start:
  while (node) {
    stack.push(node);   // save the value of the argument.
    node = node->left;  // redefine it the same way the recursive call would have
    goto start;         // simulate the recursive call
```

when executed beginning with `start` is equivalent to

```
  while (node) {
    stack.push(node);   // save the value of the argument.
    node = node->left;  // redefine it the same way the recursive call would have
  }
```

We can also replace

```
  if (!stack.empty()) {
    node = stack.pop();  // restore the saved parameter value
    goto recursive_return;
  }
```

with the following

```
  if (!stack.empty()) {
    node = stack.pop();  // restore the saved parameter value
    visit(node);
    node = node->right;
    goto start;
  }
```

We have merely copied the three instructions after `recursive_return:` into the `if` body.

With this, there is no way left to arrive at the `recursive_return` label, so we can delete it along with the two following statements:

```
   // Dead code!  Delete me!
   recursive_return:
    visit(node);
    node = node->right;
```

We now have:

```
traverse(node) {
 start:
  while (node) {
    stack.push(node);   // save the value of the argument.
    node = node->left;  // redefine it the same way the recursive call would have
  }
  if (!stack.empty()) {
    node = stack.pop();  // restore the saved parameter value
    visit(node);
    node = node->right;
    goto start;
  }
}
```

We can get rid of the last `goto start` by replacing it with an endless loop:

```
traverse(node) {
  loop {
    while (node) {
      stack.push(node);        // save the value of the argument
      node = node->left;       // redefine it the same way the recursive call would have
    }
    if (stack.empty()) break;  // original code returns, so does this!
    node = stack.pop();        // restore the saved parameter value
    visit(node);
    node = node->right;
  }
}
```

Note we are returning under the same conditions as the previous code: the stack is empty!

I will let you prove to yourself that this code does the same as what you presented, only it's a bit more efficient because it avoids some comparisons!  We never had to reason at all about pointers and stack elements.  It "just happened."

Comment: Ah, I see why data cannot be used then. That is a very good and clear point. Thanks! Is the stack holding the isolated nodes or also each node's children?

Comment: @Brandon Terms like "isolated" are pretty meaningless.  The stack holds exactly the nodes where the search has arrived but not yet visited.  This also means the subtrees rooted at these stacked nodes' right children can't have been traversed either.

Comment: I see that now. I was wondering about the right side too. Thank you very much, guys. This helps a lot! Wow, I did not realize how much I did not understand this concept. Have a great day

Comment: This post is a gold mine. It introduced a methodology to convert recursion to iteration systematically. I have been searching for years for materials talking about such topics, for example, how to organize complex nested loops neatly. May I know whether there are any books or notes that introduces similar tips systematically? Or are these methodology gained purely from personal reflection?

Comment: @modeller The basic idea of simulating what the compiler does with stack frames using an explicit stack is discussed in the 1st edition of Horowitz and Sahani's textbook. The other transformations are the kind of logic you'll see in David Greis's "Science of Programming."

Comment: Many thanks for the reference of Gries's book. I learned about the stack frames from another book, Sussman and Abelson's Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs

Comment: Hi @Gene, Thanks a lot for this explanation. I have been searching for this after I finished reading the chapter about Tree Traversal in The Science of Programming. I just want to know if I connect with you offline to discuss about the book and few queries I have.

Answer (score 1):

It's not pushing the whole tree into the stack, it pushes the left-most part of the tree. Then it begin to pop the elements and push their right-most counterparts, in ascending order.

Comment: Isn't it first pushing root? Then both left and right hand sides are being pushed. Or does the pointer isolate the links between parents and children?

Comment: The pointer is a node. It pushes the root node, yes... it has a value (data), and two childs (left and right), but you're not pushing the child nodes, their reference is "inside" the root node.

Comment: Ok, so does my thinking make sense: The stack is containing nodes rather than trees explicitly? Since it is a node pointer, we point at the nodes but the links to children are just within the node and that is how we are able to traverse to right children after being popped? I was thinking too literally before. I was thinking as the tree itself is being pushed over and over again. But I must think of memory location(s) rather than a literal link of nodes.

Comment: Any node is a whole tree. Or rather, a tree is just an arbitrary node we conveniently call "root".